# get checked boxes value by post in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm getting database from database and each row has a id and im showing it like this in html

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value"1">test1</td></tr>    
<td><input type="checkbox" value"2">test2</td></tr>
```

and so on...

now lets say that user checked ten check boxes out of 15 and then clicked submit .
how to get values of those boxes in php???

Comment: So you have nested databases?

Answer (score 2):

Your checkboxes need to have a name & a value attribute:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test1' value='1'> Test1
<input type='checkbox' name='test2' value='1'> Test2
```

then when that is posted you can access the values in PHP via $_POST:

```
$test1 = $_POST['test1']
$test2 = $_POST['test2']
```

Keep in mind that the values will only be returned if the box is checked, so most likely instead of the above PHP, you're more than likely just going to want to check if the value exists.

Answer (score 0):

give the checkboxes names:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value"2" name='test'>test2</td></tr>
```

Than in php just read the request

```
$test = $_REQUEST['test']
```

if the OP doesn't have these checkboxes inside of a , any amount of PHP code will make absolutely no difference (FROM [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender))

Comment: but how to get checked boxes?

Comment: Don't you mean `$_POST['test']`? I'd also add that if the OP doesn't have these checkboxes inside of a `<form>`, any amount of PHP code will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: that gets all the 'checked boxes' as long as they all have names they will go into the $_REQUEST var on the get or post

Comment: @gmail, what do you mean by *get*?

Comment: both _POST and _GET go into the _REQUEST var

Answer (score 0):

they will be in either the $_GET or the $_POST array

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1"><label>Test 1</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="2"><label>Test 1</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="3"><label>Test 3</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}
}
}
?>
```